# Updates to GNOME always cause breakage due to Smartcard settings not being available

Tags: gdm, session, gnome-session

So, this is a headache when you use Yubikeys or smartcards, but to disable Smartcard support in GUI, you have to remove it from the session environments.

Unfortunately, this causes some headaches, as even if you follow instructions such as those in [this question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339157/disable-smartcard-integration-in-hirsute), package updates can occasionally overwrite `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session` and `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session` which undo those changes.  This bit me in the butt today and it took nearly an hour and a half for me to debug this and get back to a usable state on my 22.04 system.

**My** solution as an insane power user was to create a SystemD unit needed before `graphical.target` and forcibly removes the `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard` references in both files as a perpetual fix during the boot process, but I'm wondering if there's a way to override the *session* referred to in the boot process so I don't *have* to alter the files that're overwritten during some updates.

Where does the system get its definitions of what *session* file to use in `sessions`, and is it possible for me to override it so that it loads a *custom* `.session` file always that will NEVER have the lines that I need to remove in it, thereby not having to go with my 'power user' approach?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from IRC that I think will work, and it involves the use of `dpkg-divert`.

Essentially, `dpkg-divert` can hold local rules such that when a specific file is going to be overwritten by a package, I can tell it to store the file elsewhere.

To that end...

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session.dist --rename /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session
```

... is the command that I was given to use.  It redirects `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session` writes to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session.dist` instead, thereby retaining my login session settings so my system doesn't explode.

From there, I simply make a copy of `gnome-login.session.dist` as `gnome-login.session` and the system will no longer overwrite the file I'm wanting to keep the same from update to update, while it will continue to keep `gnome-login.session` with my changes (in theory).

Thank you to IRC chat for the solution for this!